# Annuity or Angle Operation Symbol in LaTeX

Tags: math, latex, symbols, angle

How do I set the symbol for the *angle* or *annuity* operation in LaTeX? Specifically, this is the actuarial *a* angle *s* = (1-v<sup>s</sup>)/i.

Comment: I wish SO had latex rendering... :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a *very* comprehensive list of LaTeX symbols, see [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf). Worth printing out and keeping under your pillow. Page 95 has some code that may do what you want.

Answer (score 6):

I've looked at [Life's Contingency's Package](http://maths.dur.ac.uk/stats/courses/AMII/am.html), various Actuarial Outpost [forum](http://www.actuarialoutpost.com/actuarial_discussion_forum/showthread.php?t=113896) [threads](http://www.actuarialoutpost.com/actuarial_discussion_forum/showthread.php?p=2200212), and the [Comprehensive Symbol List](ftp://tug.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-letter.pdf) for LaTeX, and combined the best into the following macros:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lcroof}[1]{
  \hbox{\vtop{\vbox{%
      \hrule\kern 1pt\hbox{%
        $\scriptstyle #1$%
        \kern 1pt}}\kern1pt}%
    \vrule\kern1pt}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\angle}[1]{
  _{\lcroof{#1}}}
```

You can then use this macro for the problem's example by typing

```
 $a\angle{s}$
```

If you need a full set of actuarial symbols, you should use the [Life's Contingency's Package](http://maths.dur.ac.uk/stats/courses/AMII/am.html) `lifecon`. Using `lifecon`, you can set the above by typing

```
 $a_{\lcroof{s}}$
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with the actuarial symbol and the subscript/superscript, sooo I made a package to make my life easier and help other.

Plus, I’ve add some shortcut to save time.

The project [page](https://vigou3.gitlab.io/actuarialsymbol/) and the [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/actuarialsymbol).

All you need is the actuarialsymbol package.

At the beginning of the code you have to write

```
\usepackage{actuarialsymbol}
```

For the sub/superscript

```
\actsymb['subscripLeft']['superscriptL']{<middle>}{'subscriptR'}{'superscriptR'}
```

Example of output:

[image]

[image]

Example of shortcut for actuarial symbol :
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've been doing some typesetting for a professor of mine and it turns out I needed some help producing the accumulated value of an annuity notation.

I asked this question on the tex stack exchange [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383754/negation-like-symbol-with-text-numbers-underneath)

The result that [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek) produced was

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\NegationLike}[1]{%
  \mathop{%
    \mathpalette\@NegationLike{#1}%
  }%
  % A little space is added automatically,
  % if a math ord atom follows.
}
\newdimen\BarLineWidth
\newcommand*{\@NegationLike}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: argument
  \vbox{%
    % The rule thickness of \overline or \underline
    % is available in the font dimen register 8
    % of the math family 3 of the current size.
    \BarLineWidth=%
      \the\fontdimen8%
      \ifx\displaystyle#1\textfont
      \else\ifx\textstyle#1\textfont
      \else\ifx\scriptstyle#1\scriptfont
      \else\scriptscriptfont
      \fi\fi\fi
      3\relax
    % The rule at the top
    \hrule height\BarLineWidth
    % Move the box with the vertical line
    % as height as the top of the upper line
    % to get a better corner.
```

Which produces:
[accumulated value of annuity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWUKW.png)

Answer (score 0):

\annu
A good list of latex symbols can be found here http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Comment: That document shows you how to define the \annu macro, not that it is a common macro